# Basic URL structure to call Vimeo API?

Tags: android, ios, basic-authentication, vimeo-api

I'm building an app for a client who hosts private videos on Vimeo. The app needs to be able to do nothing more than play a specific video based on the Video ID.

I really don't want a full blown OAuth library bloating the app, but I simply can't figure out how to structure an HTTP(S) request to get video info (which will hopefully include a path to the MP4).

I've got the endpoint as

```
GET
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/:videoID
```

and I've got the Auth Header that Vimeo provides for my registered app.

```
Authorization: Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

But unfortunately I'm getting a `401` from fiddler when I try to hit it.

How do I request a video without a full blown OAuth implementation when the video is listed as Private?

At the end of the day, all I really need is the path to the MP4 so that I can stream it to the device's native media player (using an intent).

Comment: Did it work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35520783/vimeo-video-play-in-android-native/35543970#35543970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That basic auth header only works for the oauth endpoints. If you want to make an API request you need to use the authenticated authorization header from your app page, or [generate a new token](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/authentication)

Comment: Right, but when I use the same URL but add the `Bearer` header that's provided to me, I get a `406` exception.

Comment: Are you providing any additional headers? That error (http://httpstatus.es/406) means that you are requesting a response format that we do not support. Check your accept header.

Comment: Ah, that was it (and wasn't clear anywhere that I could find). `Accept: application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.0`